# Load video from assets into HTML5 webview - Android

Tags: android, video, html5-video, android-assets

Like the title says, I need to load a video (.mp4) from the assets folder into a WebView.
I've tried a couple of things:

//First

```
String webpage = "<!doctype html><head><meta charset='utf-8'></head><body><video id='video' controls='controls' autoplay='autoplay' height=" + m.getHeight() + " width=" + m.getWidth() + "><source src='file:///android_asset/1003/landscape_1003_1_m864.mp4' /></video></body></html>";

wv.loadData(webpage, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

//Second

Load the same webpage but using the loadUrl() method

```
wv.loadUrl(webpage);
```

//Third

Loading the exact same webpage but with another method

```
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", webpage,"text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

I've tried to change the first parameter to null,also the webpage, ...

Everything has to be added dynamically (the webview itself, the url to the video, the width, height, ...) so making a XML file is not an option.

A lot of solutions I've found on the internet was to move the video to the Raw folder or SD card, but that is not an option (business decision).

It would be nice if somebody could help me.

P.S. If you could help me with the exact same thing but showing the video in a videoview with all the controls like a html5 video element (play, pause, seekbar, fullscreen) feel free!

Comment: hey @ceetn if yu had got the proper answer for this pls do post the answer

Comment: Sorry it's just not possible.

Comment: thanks for the reply... and do you have any idea about same loading from sd card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. Unfortunately I didn't find a solution. Instand of this I just do something like this:

- Open the website in webview
- When user opens the link which ends .mp4 I open new activity with video player.
- Passing url
- Open video

  ```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  parent = (TabLayout)this.getParent();
          setContentView(R.layout.XXXXXXXXXX);
          l = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.webL);
          Resources res = getResources();
          mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
          mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);                
          mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
          mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
          mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
          mWebView.loadUrl(res.getString(R.string.XXXXXX));   
          mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
          mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
          {
              @Override
              public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
              {
                  super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                  l.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                        
              }

              @Override
              public void onPageStarted (WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
              {
                  super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                  l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              }

              @Override
              public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
              {
                  if (url.endsWith(".mp4") )
                  {                           
                      data.url = url;
                      Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoPlayer.class);
                      startActivity(intent);
                      return true;
                  } 
                  else 
                  {
                      return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                  }
              }

          });

  }
  ```

..and my video player:

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Activity
{
private VideoView mVideoView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.video);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_video); 

    mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(data.url));
    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

could you use below code and let me know if this work remember android 2.2 will support html5 .

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset", 

                        "<video src=\"diagram1.mp4\" />",  mimetype, encoding, null);


 final String mimetype = "text/html";
    final String encoding = "UTF-8";
```